# C++ filling array issue

Tags: c++

I have a function that fills an array based on user input

The program works fine in this test case but it asks the user for one more number than needed.

```
void fill_array(char a[], int size)
{
char next;
const char SENTIEL ='.';
int index=0;
cin >> next;


  while ((next !=SENTIEL) && (index < size))
{
   a[index] = next;
   index++;
   cin >> next;

}

cout << a[0];
cout << a[1];
cout << a[2];
cout << a[3];
cout << a[4];
cout << a[5];
cout << a[6];
cout << a[7];
cout << a[8];
cout << a[9];   
}




int main()
{
int const MAX=10;
char b[MAX];
fill_array(b,MAX);
}
```

this returns the correct numbers but it has one more to ask.

Comment: you should increment the index at the end of the loop iteration.

Comment: I swear I saw this same exact question earlier...

Comment: What should happen if the user enters less than 10 numbers? Your array will contain garbage after the last entered element.

Comment: [Here's the original.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630750/c-array-filler-issue) Please do not delete questions and re-ask them. It may lead you to a question-ban.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please change:

```
  while ((next !=SENTIEL) && (index < size))
{
   a[index] = next;
   index++;
   cin >> next;

}
```

to

```
while ( ( cin >> next) && ( next !=SENTIEL) && ( index < size))
    {
       a[index] = next;
       index++;

    }
```

also delete frist `cin >> next;` outside the loop, and obviously initialize `next`,  and it's OK

Comment: value of next is garbbage. There is a chance it can be equal to SENTIEL

Comment: This change stores SENTIEL in the array and the original didn't

Answer (score 2):

You are asking for `cin >> next` outside the loop (1 time) then you are asking for `cin >> next` `size` time which leads to: size + 1 times.

You should use a for loop (and of course remove the outsider `cin >> next`):

```
for (int index = 0; (next !=SENTIEL) && (index < size); index++)
{
   a[index] = next;
   cin >> next;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Intialise character `next` with some other character than `SENTIEL` and then read `next` before `index` is incremented.

```
char next = ' ';
const char SENTIEL ='.';
int index=0;
while ((next !=SENTIEL) && (index < size))
{
  cin >> next;
  a[index] = next;
  index++;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you can do something like this,

```
while ((index < size) && ((cin>>next) && next!=SENTIEL) )
{
   a[index] = next;
   index++;
}
```

With this, If the 1st input is SENTIEL you won't enter the loop.